# Audio not playing in HTML using <script> tag

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'm trying to get an audio file to play in the background and it isn't working, any insight on it?

```
        <audio id="bgmusic" preload hidden loop src="music.mp3"></audio>
        <script>
         function Play() {
         var $audio = $('#bgmusic');
         $audio.get(0).play();
         }
        </script>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO; please do not use offensive/rude language, as it triggers the automatic content filters (edited).

Comment: @GreenOrb... are you invoking the play function anywhere which you have defined in the script tag?

Comment: @sandeepjoshi ah, of course. im sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<audio id="bgmusic" preload hidden loop src="music.mp3"></audio>
    <script>
        function Play() {
        var audio = "music.mp3";
        audio.play();
     }
    </script>
```